How to set a Fan control policy in openBMC?
I've never tried the Yocto project. However, I was tasked with changing OpenBMC to allow fan control. I think I have modified the ".dts file" to set the GPIO and Fan preferences. By the way, I don't know how to change the Threshold Value. (e.g. when the temperature is 60 degrees Celsius, PWM operates at 100, and at 80 degrees Celsius, PWM operates at 200.) Where do I need to change these values, and what do I need to change? And is it possible to change the value with IPMITool without adding any code to change the auto mode, manual mode and control the fan speed?
In order to change the source code, I am printing Hello World from a Yocto project using Poky.
